# Have poblem with double-fetching using Zustand

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I attempted to refactor the logic of a React component by extracting part of the logic related to isLoading and error handling into a custom hook called useFetching, and the observation logic into useObserver. However, I observed that there are two simultaneous requests being sent to the server, and the observer, which should start working after the isLoading state changes, is not functioning as expected.

The most interesting part is that after I changed the entire logic from Zustand store to regular useState, the issue with double fetch requests ceased. Moreover, when I moved [isLoading, setIsLoading] from useFetching into the component itself, the observer started working again. Why does this happen?
main component

```
import React, {OlHTMLAttributes, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {fetchTopics} from "../../../shared/api/topic.ts";
import {Topic} from "../../../entities/topic";
import {useTopicStore} from "../model/store.ts";
import {TopicInt} from "../model/models.ts";
import classes from './topicList.module.sass'
import {useFetching, useObserver} from "../../../shared/lib/hooks";

export const TopicList: React.FC<OlHTMLAttributes<HTMLOListElement>> = ({...props}) => {
    const setChosenTopic = useTopicStore(state => state.setChosenTopic)
    const topics = useTopicStore(state => state.topics)
    const totalCount = useTopicStore(state => state.totalCount)
    const setTopics = useTopicStore(state => state.setTopics)
    const setTotalCount = useTopicStore(state => state.setTotalCount)
    // const [topics, setTopics] = useState<TopicInt[]>([])
    // const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState<number>(0)
    const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1)
    const [limit] = useState<number>(12)
    const fetch = useCallback(async (page: number, limit: number) => {
        fetchTopics(page, limit).then((data) => {
            setTopics(data.topics)
            setTotalCount(data.count)
            console.log(data, [...topics, ...data.topics], page)
        })
    }, [page, limit])
    const [fetching, isLoading, error] = useFetching(fetch)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetching(page, limit)
    }, [page, limit]);
    const chooseTopic = (topicId: TopicInt) => () => {
        setChosenTopic(topicId)
    }


    const scroll = useRef<HTMLOListElement>(null)
    const wheel = (e: WheelEvent) => {
        if (scroll.current) {
            scroll.current.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
        }
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if(scroll.current) {
            scroll.current.addEventListener("wheel", wheel, {passive: false});
        }
    }, []);
    const observableDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    useObserver(isLoading, observableDiv, page < Math.ceil(totalCount/limit), () => {
        setPage(page => page + 1)
    })
    return (
        <div onScroll={e=>e.preventDefault()} className={classes.topicContainer}>
            <ol ref={scroll} className={classes.topicList} {...props}>
                {topics.map(topic =>
                    <Topic key={topic._id} onClick={chooseTopic(topic)}>{topic.title}</Topic>
                )}
                {isLoading && <></>}
                <div ref={observableDiv} style={{width: 100, height: 10, padding: 10}}/>
            </ol>
            <div className={classes.transparentBlock}/>
            {error}
            <button onClick={()=>setPage(page=>page+1)}>add</button>
        </div>

    );
};
```

store.ts

```
import {create} from "zustand";
import {TopicInt} from "./models.ts";
interface TopicListStore {
    topics: TopicInt[] | [],
    chosenTopic: TopicInt | null,
    totalCount: number
    setTopics(topics: TopicInt[]): void
    setChosenTopic(id: TopicInt): void
    setTotalCount(count:number): void
}

export const useTopicStore = create<TopicListStore>((set)=>({
    topics: [],
    chosenTopic: null,
    totalCount: 0,
    setTopics(topics) {
        set((state)=>({topics: [...state.topics, ...topics]}))
    },
    setChosenTopic(chosenTopic) {
        set({chosenTopic})
    },
    setTotalCount(totalCount) {
        set({totalCount})
    },
}))
```

useFetching.tsx

```
import { useState} from 'react';

type FetchingFunction = (...args: any) =>Promise<any>;

type UseFetchingResult = [(...args: any) => void, boolean, string];

export const useFetching = (callback: FetchingFunction): UseFetchingResult => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>('');

    const fetching = async (...args: any) => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            await callback(...args)
        } catch (e: any) {
            setError(e.message);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }

    return [fetching, isLoading, error];
};
```

useOdserver.ts

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
export const useObserver = (isLoading: boolean, ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>, observeCondition: any, callback: ()=>void) => {
    const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoading) {
            return
        }
        console.log('ok')
        observer.current?.disconnect()
        const cb = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting && observeCondition) {
                callback()
            }
        }
        observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(cb)
        ref.current && observer.current.observe(ref.current)
    }, [isLoading]);
}
```

Also, if I replace the condition in useObserver with something like page < 3, the first render will go up to page 3, but the second render will only get the data for the first page. It's kind of breaking my brain.